# Can I get store configuration value in layout.xml file?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, configuration

I have created a module in which I have some setting in admin panel for layout.

My `layout.xml` code (in this I have added link in top links):

```
<reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" ifconfig="mbyte/mbyte_links/map_header">
                <label>Store locator</label>
                <url>storelocator/index/index</url>
                <title>Store Locator</title>
                <prepare>true</prepare>
                <position>2</position>
        </action>
```

Like I have added `ifconfig="mbyte/mbyte_links/map_header"` in action to check weather it is enable or not in configuration setting.

I have also one more configuration setting for `<title>`. Now my question starts

**Is this possible to get configuration value which I have set in admin panel and directly set here in layout file, if yes what is the procedure to do this?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use helpers to retrieve system values required by layout action params.

**Create a helper in your module**
`app/code/local/Mbyte/Links/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php
class Mbyte_Links_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function getTitleFromConfig()
    {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig('mbyte/mbyte_links/title');
    }
}
```

**Then in your layout.xml you can use**

```
<reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" ifconfig="mbyte/mbyte_links/map_header">
            <label helper="mbyte/data/getTitleFromConfig" />
            <url>storelocator/index/index</url>
            <title helper="mbyte/data/getTitleFromConfig"/>
            <prepare>true</prepare>
            <position>2</position>
    </action>
```