# Config values in an .xml file

Tags: magento-1.9

I have an `.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<config>

<timezone>CET</timezone>

<days>1 2 3 4 5</days>

</config>
```

And I would like to have those values be changeable from the admin panel. 
So I created a system config where values can be requested like: `Mage::getStoreConfig('twilio/call_forward/weekdays');`

How can I get this value in the `.xml` file?

**Edit:**

Also, my problem is that the `.xml` file has to be located in the root folder of magento. So in order to call `Mage::getStoreConfig('twilio/call_forward/weekdays');` is have to first

```
define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once MAGENTO . '/app/Mage.php';
```

Which as far as I know can only be done in php.

Is there a way to call a helper from the root folder?

Comment: try this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/63197/20064

Comment: Please see my edit

Answer (score 1):

By default, Magento will not "pick up" values from custom XML files. Only XML files with locations and names reserved in the system (i.e. `etc/system.xml etc/config.xml` and many others).

If you want to use your own XML file, you need to register it in the system. Here is a good example [Admin monitoring](https://github.com/firegento/firegento-adminmonitoring/tree/develop/src/app/code/community/FireGento/AdminMonitoring/etc) . Look at the `adminmonitoring.xml`

it's a custom XML file with a configuration. Configuration from that file is loaded by [FireGento](https://github.com/firegento/firegento-adminmonitoring/blob/develop/src/app/code/community/FireGento/AdminMonitoring/Model/Config.php) Model. The `loadModulesConfiguration` method is used for this purpose. The method allows you to read configuration from a custom XML file and merge the configuration with the global one.

Hope it will help.